# create a Object with number of Objects and push them to a array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

My requirement is to push 6 objects to array with out index the final array should be single array with direct objects without index 0,1,2,3

```
{headerName: '', field: 'sadf'},
{headerName: '', field: 'sadf'},
{headerName: '', field: 'sadf'},
{headerName: '', field: 'sadf'},
```

Comment: array without index? what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

You could use .push() method of Array.

```
let arr = [];
arr.push({headerName: '', field: 'sadf'});
arr.push({headerName: '', field: 'sadf'});
...
```